# Finding all solutions to the equation $|||||x|-1|-1|-1|-1|=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I was presented this question by a student I was tutoring:

> Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Find all solutions of the equation $$|||||x|-1|-1|-1|-1|=0.$$

What I explained to the student:

Given $|||||x|-1|-1|-1|-1|=0$, one can drop the outermost absolute value bars, and place the plus/minus symbol on the right side, like this: $$||||x|-1|-1|-1|-1=\pm 0=0 \implies ||||x|-1|-1|-1|=1.$$

Repeating this process, $$|||x|-1|-1|-1=\pm 1 \implies |||x|-1|-1|=0,2.$$
And again, $$||x|-1|-1=0,2 \implies |||x|-1|=1,3.$$
And yet again, $$|x|-1=\pm1, \pm3 \implies |x|=0,2,4.$$
Finally, we arrive with $\boxed{x=-4,-2,0,2,4}$.

Was this approach okay? How did I do as far as finding the solutions go?

Comment: Do you assume $x$ to be real?

Comment: I think what you did was fine.  Maybe I'm missing something?  I checked all of the solutions, and they work.

Comment: +1, nice exercise to make sure that students understand the concept of absolute value.

Comment: interesting problem... perhaps it can be generalised to $n$ times

Comment: this is an interesting problem... it would be very nice if there is a systematic way to transform similar problems into one of finding roots of a polynomial equation... in this case the polynomial equation would be the expansion of $(x-4)(x-2)x(x+2)(x+4)=0$

Comment: @user46944 I know that this is a late comment, but indeed it seems we *were* missing something. An absolute value cannot be negative, so I had to make the necessary edit to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calculations look solid to me. Since it seems like you understand the computational aspects of this type of problem, I'd just like to offer a geometric perspective on the problem. Here's a graph of the function $f(x)=|||||x|-1|-1|-1|-1|$ for $-7<x<7$:

[image]

The five points where the function meets the $x$-axis correspond to the five roots of the equation you calculated. Note the periodic saw-tooth nature of the function between $-4$ and $4$. Once you know that $x=0$ is a root and $x=2$ is a root, you can automatically infer from symmetry that $x=-2,x=4,x=-4$ are also roots. All that's left at this point is logically justifying that these are the only roots.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that it is not very difficult to draw the graph by hand: First we draw $y=|x|$ and move the graph downwards by 1 to get $y=|x|-1$. Then we reflect the part of the graph, which is below x-axis, to get $y=||x|-1|$. We repeat these two steps (move by $-1$, reflect negative part).

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(x) = ||x|-1|$. You have $f(x) = c$ **iff** $x=\pm(c+1)$ or $x=\pm (1-c)$.

The problem is to solve $f(f(f(f(x)))) = 0$.

This gives the possible values of $f(f(f(x)))$ as $\pm 1$.

This gives the possible values of $f(f(x))$ as $0, \pm 2$.

This gives the possible values of $f(x)$ as $\pm 1, \pm 3$.

Finally, this gives the possible values of $x$ as $0, \pm 2, \pm 4$.

The general pattern follows from this...